# Is there a bracket or brace that I can use to hold my two monitors together?

Tags: display

I have two identical monitors.  When I set them side by side, the edges don't quite sit perpindicular to one another.  This is most likely due to slight structural differences in the stands that occurred as they cooled after being released from their casts.

I can hold them together with my hands just how I want them to stay, but, of course, they move back into their natural position when I release them.

It seems there would be a sort of plastic brace that I can attach to both monitors to hold them perfectly together.  What would such a thing be call if it exists?  If there is nothing like it, what ideas do you all have as far as making such a thing?

I put this in superuser because I couldn't find a more appropriate section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question belongs here... don't worry about that.

Have you tried using something **simple**, like **tape**?  (Duct tape may work best.)

Alternatively, you may want to search [monitor mounts](http://www.google.com/search?q=montior+mounts&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=&oe=#q=monitor+mounts&hl=en&safe=active&sa=X&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&prmd=imvns&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&ei=kbKNTpiiLKfZ0QGZxpBU&ved=0CI8BEK0E&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=82e0078552b6f932&biw=1440&bih=782) and see if anything there is exactly what you’re looking for.

Comment: Jeez, if I only knew [what to do with my duct tape](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/geekend/how-to-build-a-server-out-of-duct-tape/733) …

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick not funny...

Answer (score 1):

[Ergotron](http://www.ergotron.com/) makes a wide range of mounts. They will likley have something.

Comment: Other vendors with decent hardware are Chief (http://www.chiefmfg.com/), Ergotech (http://www.ergotechgroup.com/), and for something cheaper (price and quality) there's Planar (http://www.planar.com/).  IMO if you want something non-articulating, Chief and Ergotech are both a better bet than Ergotron.

Comment: It's also worth noting that **custom mounting solutions are only useful if the monitors in question can be removed from their stands**.

Answer (score 1):

A big binder clip works well for me!

Answer (score 1):

I recently was struggling to keep my monitors together next to each other, it was due to an imbalance in the bases, i kept trying to browse forums everywhere, but i could find a solution.

What i had done before was that i tapped a little piece of duck tape to one corner of a monitor and that kinda kept them together, however they would slide off every other day which was annoying.

That was until i came across velcro strips, which is basically double sided tape, except the side that goes outwards is velcro instead of glue, the inside part comes covered with paper, you just gotta cut it to your specific measurements, peel it off and stick one of each to each monitor and voila, your monitors will now stay together, leveled and next to each other.

You can find any brand on amazon under "velcro tape" they cost anywhere from $8 to $12.

Hope i helped someone.